# php array from XML

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have this array, that a got from a webservice so the array what I get is a XML with data.
I want to print each register I dont know how to do it. I tried many ways to print it and I can not.

```
Array

(
    [Record] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Field] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => licsa
                            [1] => b0z833
                            [2] => 1381768597
                            [3] => 0xF447
                            [4] => -12.047333333333333
                            [5] => -77.12163333333334
                            [6] => 0.0
                            [7] => Licsa
                            [8] => licsa
                        )
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Field] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => licsa
                            [1] => b0z834
                            [2] => 1381767415
                            [3] => 0x000C
                            [4] => -12.047633333333334
                            [5] => -77.12366666666667
                            [6] => 0.0
                            [7] => Licsa
                            [8] => licsa
                        )

                )

        )

)


Array ( [Record] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Field] => Array ( [0] => licsa [1] => b0z833 [2] => 1381768597 [3] => 0xF447 [4] => -12.047333333333333 [5] => -77.12163333333334 [6] => 0.0 [7] => Licsa [8] => licsa ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Field] => Array ( [0] => licsa [1] => b0z834 [2] => 1381767415 [3] => 0x000C [4] => -12.047633333333334 [5] => -77.12366666666667 [6] => 0.0 [7] => Licsa [8] => licsa ) ) ) ) 1
```

to print that I use ....

Comment: You want to convert this array to XML?

Comment: XML to Array OP says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array's are accessed using `$array['key']` and `stdClass`'s are accessed using `$object->key`, so according to your `print_r` output, you'd have to access it using:

```
echo 'licsa = ' . $array['Record'][0]->Field[0];
```

etc.

You can also loop through it:

```
foreach ($array['Record'] as $record) {
    echo 'licsa = ' . $record->Field[0];
}
```

Comment: thankx, Now I am able to show the data in a table

Answer (score 0):

A little vague, but try:

```
foreach($array['Record'] as $object) {
    foreach($object->Field as $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx It helps me a lot, now I can see the data from the XML

Comment: I need to see each register independent in order to work with the data, Can yo help me, please?? and now I see the data like these--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------licsab0z83313817704230x000C-12.047283333333333-77.121733333333340.0Licsalicsalicsab0z83413817712570xF447-12.047666666666666-77.123683333333330.0Licsalicsa

Comment: @user2879678: You'll have to give a lot more info on what you want to access or display.  Also, what is "each register"?  Maybe edit your question to show formatting etc.

Comment: for example: I need to access to "[Record][0][Field][0]=> licsa" or "[Record][1][Field][2]=> 1381767415".    It is clear??

Comment: @user2879678: The Records are objects use -> `echo $array['Record'][0]->Field[0];`

Comment: You could also simplify if only Record is there `$array = array_map(function ($object) { return (array)$object; }, $array['Record']);` then access with `$array[0]['Field'][0]`

Answer (score 0):

To convert XML to an array, assuming the original array is inside `$xml_original`, do this:

```
$xml_array = unserialize(serialize(json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml_original), 1)));
```

All objects should be converted into arrays at this point.